# I'm trying to display webrtc format like :https://test.webrtc.org/. but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webrtc, simplewebrtc

I'm a newbie in webrtc. I'm trying to use https://github.com/webrtc/testrtc this code but it's not working. showing some file missing errors. I wanna show like this : https://test.webrtc.org/

Comment: What is error ? Which url you are opening?

Comment: You need to post exact error  so that we can help.